# ASM Compiler, how to bootstrap?

Tags: python, assembly

I have written my own high level ASM language in Python.
Is it possible to bootstrap my ASM language? If yes, are there any useful docs that describe how to do it step by step?

This is a snippet of loop:

```
# comment

_data:
  set x0 0
end

_main:
  prt 'Start'
  jmp asd
  prt 'Middle'
  lbl asd
  prt 'End'
  jmp loop
  ext
end

# loop 0..9
loop:
  jmp loop_init
  lbl loop_start
  prt x0
  inc x0
  lbl loop_init
  ieq x0 10
  jmt loop_end
  jmf loop_start
  lbl loop_end
  ext
end
```

Comment: To bootstrap, write an implementation in the new language.  Having a working Python version can serve as guide for what needs to be implemented — hand translate each line of Python into your language.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers) for typical steps/stages.    See also ["The development of compilers for new programming languages first developed in an existing language but then rewritten in the new language and compiled by itself, is another example of the bootstrapping notion."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Compilers)

Comment: Does it mean that I need to be able to write all the used functionality from A to B ? Where A is Python and B is ASM ?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want here. An assembly language is, by definition, a low-level language. The tool to convert it to machine code is usually called an "assembler" (it doesn't "compile" anything because the assembly instructions already correspond straightforwardly to actual machine language). If this language doesn't correspond to an existing architecture, what is supposed to execute it?

Comment: Or are you trying to ask how to write an emulator for this imagined architecture? That would basically amount to a program which models the CPU's behavior, i.e. each machine instruction is implemented as a small program which manipulates the state of the CPU (instruction pointer, registers, address pointers) and/or the (emulated model of the) RAM. Simple machine architectures for learning how processors work often also have a simple set of I/O instructions in the machine language itself; they might turn on or off lights in the emulator's GUI, or read and write strings to the emulator console.

Answer (score 2):

To bootstrap, write an implementation in the new language.

See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) for typical steps/stages. See also ["The development of compilers for new programming languages first developed in an existing language but then rewritten in the new language and compiled by itself, is another example of the bootstrapping notion."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Compilers)

Having a working Python version can serve as guide for what needs to be implemented — hand translate each line of Python into your language.

A working implementation in any already existing language (from assembly to Python to C#) is also very helpful in getting through Stage 1.  In Stage 1, you can run your new language source code implementation through the Python version, for example, and that will then produce an executable (presumably) that you can use to self-compile.

When working on a Stage 1 version, then things can go quicker by avoiding use of complex features in the new language.  For an assembler that might mean something like not using macros or templates, records/structures, or not relying on more complex error detection/messaging, which you might have if supporting features like function signatures.

You're basically writing an assembler in assembly language.  You'll need capabilities like a parser, mnemonic lookup/translation, symbol table, machine code generation, fixups (or two pass) — similar to what you already have in Python, but Python makes dictionaries and other data structures easy to use.

Usually, bootstrapping is done in the direction toward the new, higher level language than existing, as with C#, for example, when they wrote their compiler in C++, then eventually translated it to C#.  You're going in the other direction, though should be a good learning exercise.